# How to fix the div aligning inside <table>

Tags: html, css

How can I have align `Name` with title/phone/email and when I expand my page the aligning is messing up as shown in screen shot 1 and 2

I have tried: `style="display:initial;position: relative; "`
but does not do any good.

[image]
[image]

```
<table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="data2Col  first " colspan="2">
        <div>
          <span class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap" scope="row" style="display:inline-block; ">Name </span>

          <span class="data2Col"> <a href="/1233" onclick="openTab('1233','Erich Schulz'); return false" target="_blank">Erich Schulz</a> </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row">Title</th>
      <td class="data2Col "><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row">Phone</th>
      <td class="data2Col "><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id4:j_id7">(555) 555-5555</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  last " scope="row">Email</th>
      <td class="data2Col  last "><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8"><a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you need to do like `div { margin: auto; }`

Comment: did not help me same behavior

Comment: why don't you also use two TDs in the first table row? That would solve the problem.

Comment: What CSS are you currently using? Your provided code won't give us the result seen in the image. But are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/tcrszgq6/

Answer (score 0):

As written in my comment, I would replace the `span` elements in the first table row by `td` elements (and remove the `colspan=2` from that row):

```
<table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="data2Col  first ">
        <div>
          <td class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap" scope="row" style="display:inline-block; ">Name </td>

          <td class="data2Col"> <a href="/1233" onclick="openTab('1233','Erich Schulz'); return false" target="_blank">Erich Schulz</a> </td>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row">Title</th>
      <td class="data2Col "><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row">Phone</th>
      <td class="data2Col "><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id4:j_id7">(555) 555-5555</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  last " scope="row">Email</th>
      <td class="data2Col  last "><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8"><a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or, if for some reason you have to keep those `span` elements, wrap them with `<td>...</td>`

Additional edit: As spencerlarry wrote correctly, the first one is actually a `<th>` tag. But that probably won't make a difference regarding the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing both `span` elements with `th` and `td`

```
<span class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap" scope="row" style="display:inline-block; ">Name </span>
<span class="data2Col"> <a href="/1233" onclick="openTab('1233','Erich Schulz'); return false" target="_blank">Erich Schulz</a> </span>
```

Shown below:

```
<th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row">Name </th>
<td class="data2Col"> <a href="/1233" onclick="openTab('1233','Erich Schulz'); return false" target="_blank">Erich Schulz</a> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the first column in one piece? Please change the first `<tr>` block  as follows:

```
<tr>
<td class="labelCol  first">
    <span class="vfLabelColTextWrap" scope="row">Name </span>
</td>
<td class="data2Col">
    <a href="/1233" onclick="openTab('1233','Erich Schulz'); return false" target="_blank">Erich Schulz</a>
</td>
</tr>
```